# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) error and i just cant understand why?

Tags: php, class, syntax-error

I am trying to write this simple class in php as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'db_con.php';
class logg{

    private $db;
    private $username = $_POST['usr_name']; 
    private $password = $_POST['usr_pass'];
    private $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE nick='$username'";

function __construct(){
    $this->db = new DB();
}

function loggIn(){
    try{
        $res = $this->db->fetch($query)
        foreach($res as $row) {
            $dbusername = $row['nick'];
            $dbpassword = $row['pass']; }
        if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
            header('Location: index.php');
        } catch (Exception $e){
        echo'Wrong login information!'
        }
    }
}   

function loggOut(){
    session_destroy();
}
}

?>
```

but i keep getting the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) and i just cant figure out why! Even if i remove theese rows:

```
    private $username = $_POST['usr_name']; 
    private $password = $_POST['usr_pass'];
```

i instead get the following error:

```
    ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in
```

im certain the error is a real simple one, but I just can't seem to figure it out..!
Any help appriciated!

Comment: Default values for property declarations can only be constant values, not variables or expressions.

Comment: You should set (but still declare it private outside of the constructor) username, password and query inside your constructor.

Comment: It baffles me that answers are being written as comments all over the place nowadays. This is a Q&A database, not a chatroom or live helpdesk!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from a syntax error on your `echo` line, the actual problem resulting in this particular error is that **you can only initialise class members like that with *constants***.

Since constants never begin with a `$`, your initialisations exhibit a syntax error.

**You'll have to assign to those members in the class's constructor, instead**, just like you do for `$db`.

Comment: Thnx for the help!  Greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semi-colon here:

```
echo'Wrong login information!' // <-- HERE
```